# docker-compose network / ports handling

Tags: docker, hbase, apache-zookeeper, docker-network

I have two components: [hbas&ookeeper as single container](https://github.com/dajobe/hbase-docker/blob/master/start-hbase.sh) and hbase-printer (my java code) in my host. My goal is to print the content of some hbase table.
The problem is that the connection to 2181 (zookeeper port) succeed but than it looks like I'm getting directed to side randomly port to communicate and this port is not exposed.
I'm using `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  hbase:
    image: dy1-dockerv2-local.jfrog.io/hbase:latest
    restart: always
    hostname: hbase-docker
    ports:
      - "60010:60010"
      - "60000:60000"
      - "60020:60020"
      - "60030:60030"
      - "9095:9095"
      - "8085:8085"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "2181:2181"
      - "9091:9091"
      - "9090:9090"
    expose:
      - "9091"
      - "2181"
    volumes:
      - ./data/hbase:/data
      - ./logs/hbase/:/opt/hbase/logs
    network_mode: "bridge"
```

In my java logs I'm getting:

```
23-02-2017 09:29:54,413 INFO [ClientCnxn]: [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x15a69d8a7a30006, negotiated timeout = 40000
23-02-2017 09:30:16,955 INFO [HBaseRPC]: [main] Problem connecting to server: hbase-docker/172.17.0.2:39521
```

In my host I can see the listening ports:

```
$ netstat -na | grep LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  ::1.2181               *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.2181                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  ::1.8080               *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  ::1.8085               *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.8085                 *.*
```

(and the rest of the ports I've defined in my `docker-compose.yml` file

And in the container I see:

```
root@hbase-docker:/# netstat -na | grep LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 172.17.0.2:39521        :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::60010                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 172.17.0.2:32785        :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::43189                :::*                    LISTEN
```

I see that the side port 39521 is available inside the container but not exposed to the host. I cannot add it to my `docker-compose.yml` because it changed randomly (looks like something between 30000-50000).
How can I expose the random port to my host?

Comment: Can you check the version of hbase installed in the container/image?

Comment: @AlexanderBlock 0.94.26 - I know it's an old one but it's the one I'm using in production (not dockerized)

Answer (score 0):

You are most like facing https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10289, which was fixed in 0.99.0 and 0.98.4. As of the comments on the answer, you are still on an old version of hbase, probably < 0.99.0.

You should try to use a newer version of hbase. You'll find one on the Docker Hub for example: https://hub.docker.com/r/dajobe/hbase/

Comment: what is  JMX MBean? are you sure this issue is related? I'm using the docker you mentioned (dajobe/hbase) - look at my link at the beginning.. but I'm using earlier version (earlier commit)

Comment: Which commit exactly did you use? I see that you use the image from dy1-`dockerv2-local.jfrog.io/hbase:latest`, is this your self-built image?

Comment: Yes, but it based on their repo: commit `8fdd3fb09891b09140cdc2bfc27222617ab2cded`

Comment: The commit message says "Update to JDK7 and HBase 0.94.26", so it sounds like HBase is < 0.99.0. Can you try to upgrade, even if JMX seems unrelated. In the comments of the issue, there is mixed talk about it affecting JMX and RMI.